# Ajax returning search query in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to follow ryan bates' screen cast [on filtering searches using ajax](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax)

I have a functioning search form.

```
= form_tag(admin_leisure_centres_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do
  = text_field_tag :querystr, params[:querystr], placeholder: "Search"
  = submit_tag "Search", :name => nil
```

and the partial is below it wrapped in a div

```
    #admin-centres 
     = render partial: "/admin/venues/venue_list",locals: {venues: leisure_centres,boroughs: boroughs}
```

here is the controller index action

```
  def index
    @body_class = "centres"
    get_leisure_centres
    if params[:querystr].present? and params[:querystr].length>2
      @leisure_centres = @leisure_centres.search(params[:querystr]).order("created_at DESC")
    end
    @boroughs=@leisure_centres.map{|l| l.borough}.uniq.sort
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

index.js.erb

```
$("#admin-centres").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("admin/venues/venue_list")) %>");
```

admin.js

```
$(function() {

    $.get($("#search-form").attr("action"), $("#search-form").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

where am i going wrong here? this just wont work! I have spent hours.

UPDATE:

It is working sort of, in that I can write a valid term and it returns nothing but if i write some like 'wedrfgthyujgkfv' it returns nil.

this is from chrome console log

```
GET http://localhost:3000/admin/leisure_centres?utf8=%E2%9C%93&querystr=qw&_=1404747537453 500 (Internal Server Error) admin.js:8435
send admin.js:8435
jQuery.extend.ajax admin.js:7987
jQuery.(anonymous function) admin.js:7511
(anonymous function) admin.js:47296
jQuery.event.dispatch admin.js:3059
elemData.handle.eventHandle admin.js:2677
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There are couple of things that i can point out but lets go one by one. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Mandeep just updated my q.

Comment: can you post your log after opening up your ajax request. Also you are not passing locals for your partial in js.erb file as you did it html.erb. You didn't pass these locals `locals: {venues: leisure_centres,boroughs: boroughs}`

Comment: Your console log mentions error in `admin.js`, but you haven't posted anything about `admin.js`.